# Xcode simulator sporadically not responding to touch events - SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios-simulator, swiftui-list

Setup: a SwiftUI `List` with `NavigationLink`s wrapped in a `NavigationView`. Tapping on the `NavigationLink` opens `DeviceInfoView` only 50% of the time. Environment: Simulator 13.2, Xcode 13.2.1. All works fine on a real device. Any insights? Thanks.

```
struct DeviceSearchView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = DeviceSearchViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                switch viewModel.searchResults {
                    // ...
                    case let .success(results):
                        List(results, id: \.imei) { res in
                            NavigationLink(destination: DeviceInfoView(imei: res.imei)) {
                                Text("IMEI: \(res.imei)")
                            }
                        }
                        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
                        .navigationTitle("Title")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "cpu")
                        Text("...").font(.headline)
                    }
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $viewModel.searchText, prompt: "IMEI").keyboardType(.numberPad)
        }
    }
}
```

...and in the viewModel:

```
@MainActor
final class DeviceSearchViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var searchResults: AsyncResult<[FindySearchResult]> = .empty
    // etc...
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. But with the little you have provided it looks like you are trying to return asynchronous work in the `body` that is not a good idea since the `body` is synchronous and gets reloaded many times. I suggest moving that `searchResults` completion handler to a class and having an `@Published` that decides what to show.

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks, but I believe this is not it - posted some more code to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

`Simulator -> Device -> Erase all content and settings...` fixed it.